# How to toggle content in Vue JS passing strings to data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to have a simple toggle function which take a minute to create in vanilla js and somehow I got stuck on this in vue.
How can I resolve the below, passing a string that should be a created var that needs to be accessed.

```
    <div @click="showData('data1')">click</div>
    <div @click="showData('data2')">click</div>
    <div @click="showData('data3')">click</div>
    <div v-show="data1">Show data 1</div>
    <div v-show="data2">Show data 2</div>
    <div v-show="data3">Show data 3</div>

data() {
    data1 : false,
    data2 : false,
    data3 : false
}


showData(curData) {

    this.data1 = false;
    this.data2 = false;
    this.data3 = false;

    this.[curData] = !this.[curData];

}
```

Comment: Use `@click="showData('data2')"`

Comment: Tried that as well, not working either.
this.[curData] is not allowed

Comment: Try it again with console.logs and tell us if function call is being executed or not. As far as I think the issue maybe with this line `this.[curData] = !this.curData;`

Comment: Yes, it shows the string correctly. 'data1', 'data2',... Also sorry for error in question, I did and do have @click attached to the element.

Comment: Then where is the issue?

Comment: Try `this[curData] = !this[curData];` but console each and every line when you can't find the issue

Comment: this.[curData] = !this.curData; --> SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Comment: Look closely what I commented. There is no `.` after `this`. People have made answers with running code below

Comment: Okay try my answer it should work as per your needs

Comment: Nah I don't downvote anything. The people who do that have one clear point in which they want the author to do proper research before putting up the question. Your code had syntax errors more than the logical ones so maybe that's why

Comment: @battaboombattabaam I downvoted it because you modified the original code twice

Comment: @Mi-Creativity, I modified it because I didn't copy the code from the original snippet, and wrote it out too quickly (my bad), but the main issue remained that the 'toggle' did not work, so when clicking on an opened one, it didn't close again. Anyway, I saw that I have been way too many hours behind the screen and at some point the obvious can simply seem confusing, Thanks anyway for your input.

Comment: When you just modify the post some comments or answers would be no more relevant to people who later come and read comments/answers

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Proof-read before posting! http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 issues with your code. First is this line `this.[curData] = !this.curData;` where the syntax of getting the passed data variable is wrong also `this.curData` would give undefined error as curData variable does not exist. Second is with the resetting of all the values to false without saving the current clicked element's value to toggle.
Try the following

```
showData(curData) {
  const value = !this[curData];
 
  this.data1 = false;
  this.data2 = false;
  this.data3 = false;

  this[curData] = value;
}
```

Comment: @battaboombattabaam By the way one more thing. You are trying to show hide divs by toggling 3 variables right? So suppose the no. of divs increase then you are forced to make more variables. I would suggest you to use an associative array e.g., `data=[]` with div information like `data['data1']=false` and use that same thing in `v-show` and in `showData()`

Answer (score 1):

[**Updated**]

A shorter alternative way to do it:

[**Code Demo**](https://codesandbox.io/s/toggle-showing-div-uf1yj?file=/src/App.vue)

```
<div @click="handleSwitchData('data1')">click</div>
<div @click="handleSwitchData('data2')">click</div>
<div @click="handleSwitchData('data3')">click</div>
<div v-show="switchData == 'data1'">Show data 1</div>
<div v-show="switchData == 'data2'">Show data 2</div>
<div v-show="switchData == 'data3'">Show data 3</div>


data() {
  return {
    switchData: "",
  };
},
methods: {
  handleSwitchData(cData) {
    this.switchData = this.switchData === cData ? "" : cData;
  },
},
```

Comment: I actually had this as well, but it doesn't toggle, because as you can see in your example as well, it doesn't close the one that was opened when clicking on the same title.

Comment: this.curData would be undefined

Comment: You can't toggle it because you're already making it `false` before toggling it